# Mobile Website Security

Tags: web-application, network, web-browser, attacks, mobile

I have a school project with the topic name
"Mobile Website security" which is a little confusing. The task is to write a report regarding the type of threats and the defenses against these threats

As from what I understand, a mobile website is basically a website that is scaled down to fit onto a mobile phone.

After googling, the word mobile security appears quite a lot, but it doesn't seem to be in the same category as a mobile website

So my questions are:

1. Does the security of a mobile website and a "full" website differ?
2. Is mobile security the same as mobile website security?

Comment: "Mobile Website Security" isn't a well-defined term. I'm not voting to close even though this question seems a bit broad as I can imagine some possible answers (mainly regarding client-side attacks such as XSS, CSRF, or open redirect), but this is really something you should ask your teacher.

Comment: Yes, this term is causing alot of confusion for me

Comment: You should probably request clarification from your teacher. We're not psychic or anything, so a vague question stumps us as well.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference in used technology and security risks between a normal website and a mobile version. Mobile website security is not really a thing while the security of mobile devices absolutely is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed nobody actually answered this question and while the questioner might be helped already, others might have the same question.

There is no significant difference between a regular website and their mobile version. You use the same technology and therefore the same risks apply to these websites. Of course, there is a big difference between securing a regular website and mobile security - They are fundamentally different.

In this specific case; asking your teacher to clarify the assignment might be your best shot. This could be the answer to your second question *"Is mobile security the same as mobile website security"* as there is no such thing is 'mobile website security' in the security industry unless your teacher meant the same.

Comment: Also to add on, what my group did was to treat mobile website security as a subset of mobile security, only picking mostly of scripting attacks, phishing, mostly browsers related attacks and got A for the assignment